крашится приложение android studio kotlin
Только начал изучать Android Studio и Kotlin, так что вопрос и употребление мной терминов может быть странным.
написал для теста приложение, которое по нажатию одной кнопки выводит снизу надпись, а по нажатию второй кнопки должно увеличивать значение переменной и выводить ее в лейбл. сделал все по примеру из интернета, но вот незадача: при нажатии второй кнопки приложение просто вылетает. и все. просто вылетает. при этом первая кнопка работает.
код и xml прилагаю:
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }
    fun toastMe(view: View){
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "ну наконец-т епт",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        myToast.show()
    }
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    fun countMe (view: View) {
        // Get the value of the text view.
        val countString = textView.text.toString()
        // Convert value to a number and increment it
        var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
        count++
        // Display the new value in the text view.
        textView.text = count.toString();
    }
}

xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="180px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.579"
        android:onClick="toastMe" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373"
        android:onClick="countMe"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

в чем проблема? буду благодарен за любые советы касательно Android Studio.

Android Studio != Android development, разрабатывать Андроид приложения можно использую и другие IDE, либо вообще без них. В вашем вопросе нет ничего касаемо Android Studio как таковой.

друг. оперировать текстом для отображения, как переменной - это за гранью разумного. По каким бы источникам ты не учился, немедленно сожги их и забудь все, что там узнал. Читай "Android. программирование для профессионалов"

спасибо. автор курса уже сожжен

окей я решил проблему. лейбл был пустой, поэтому было просто не к чему прибавлять единицу при нажатии кнопки. надо было просто указать "стартовое" значение в поле текста TextView:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222" />


на самом деле, надо было просто создать переменную типа int и с ней работать, а TextView используется только для отображения информации, в частности, значения переменной типа int.

можешь на примере кода показать как это реализовывается?

это показано в любом мало-мальски пригодном учебнике по любому языку программирования, друг. прочитай какой-нибудь, прежде чем вдохновенно творить.

В общем то тебе просто нужно держать переменную числового типа count, а не извлекать значение каждый раз из текста на экране, преобразовывая его в число и обратно в текст.
